# How to access amazon instance using localhost instead ip address?

Tags: amazon-ec2, single-instance

I create instance of amazon server. Now i can access it using ip address.
But i do not want to access amazon instance using ip address. So, any way to access amazon instance without ip from URL.

Like currently i access in URL
EX: `http://23.23.23.23/index.html`
I want to access in URL
EX: `http://localhost:8888/index.html`
8888 is just for example. Any port is ok. or any other name instead localhost is fine for me.

Let me know asap any one has a solutions or suggestion

Thanks

Comment: You cannot access an external internet website by using localhost unless you change the defination of localhost, which makes no sense, because if you do that just create a `localhost2` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Public DNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html) of the instance. This gives you a name instead of an IP.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply but public dns is long name to remember. Any way to i can make it short or give any other short name? thanks

Comment: Buy a [domain](http://www.godaddy.com/domains/domain-name-search.aspx?ci=8990) name, add this **public dns** address in the [CNAMErecord](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names). There you go.

Comment: No, i guess....

Answer (score 1):

Tou can do this in two ways

1. Use [Amazon public DNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-connect-to-instance-linux.html#using-browser)
2. Buy a domain name and make your instance available using domain name.